# Get RSS Feed From Facebook User's Wall

Tags: ios, xml, facebook, rss

I am trying to get an RSS feed from a user's wall.  I am trying this format on the URL (use the same one for one of my Facebook pages)

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=XXXXXXXXX

However, all I get is Facebook Syndication Error in the RSS, not the posts.  What is a good way I could get this info, keeping in mind I plan on using it to make a TableView in iOS of all the posts on it?

Again, remember this is for an actual user account, NOT a Facebook Page.